# Glassfish docroot and unreachable crossdomain

Tags: glassfish-3, crossdomain.xml

I am trying to access a webservice from Flex. The webserivce is deployed on Glassfish 3.1 application server. Now, Flex needs a "crossdomain.xml" file at the root (top-level) of the server.

Here is the problem: I searched and found that the crossdomain file should be inside the docroot directory (c:\Glassfish3\Glassfish\domains\domain1\docroot). That is exactly the where I put it, and yet I get a 404 when I try to reach it.

I also tried putting it under applications but it didn't work.

What should I do?

Thank you,
Ido

Comment: it seems weird. If you type http://localhost:8080 does it show you the glassfish default page? (I assume your http port is 8080)

Comment: Yes, and if I try to access http://localhost:8080/crossdomain.xml I get the file. But I need this file to be accessible through IP address.

Comment: If you try with h ttp://x.y.z.w do you get the default glassfish page? All your virtual servers have the same document root directory, or have you set a different document root directory for some of them?

Comment: Thank you for you help. I didn't do anything. I just installed glassfish and deployed a simple WAR through it's admin console - nothing more.   I need to access the service with an IP address: h ttp://10.0.0.7/crossdomain.xml.

Comment: as far as i can see you have glassfish that listen on 8080 but you want to access it from port 80. Did you set the firewall properly to redirect 80 to 8080?

Comment: Im sorry, I wrote it wrong. I want to access it like this:  h ttp://10.0.0.7:8080/crossdomain.xml.  It does not work.

Comment: If you type h ttp://10.0.0.7:8080 what page do you see? Do you get a 404 error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the answer, though I'm not sure that this is recommended.

Inside Glassfish admin console, under configurations --> server-config --> Network config --> http-listener-1.

I changed the address from "0.0.0.0" to the actual IP address of the server.

Now It works fine and I am getting access to crossdomain.xml, but as I said,  I am not so sure that this action is recommended and won't make other errors.

Thank you.

Comment: In this way you can't access the crossdomain.xml from http://localhost:8080/crossdomain.xml or any other address that point to your machine. Try it

Comment: Actualy, It is just a server so I don't mind if localhost is unreachable - It'll do for me. But still, Is there a way to solve this without making localhost unreachable?

Comment: I think the issue is elsewhere. I use glassfish in a public server and with no specific configuration I'm able to see files in doocroot. On the other hand listener=0.0.0.0 manages all incoming requests, even those direct to 10.0.0.7 So I don't understand where the problem is. sorry. If you find out a solution in the future let us know